# Enter Click in JQuery dialog textbox does not trigger __doPostBack

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a textbox in JQuery popup dialog. `Keypress` event on textbox is working perfect and catches only enter key. I want to trigger `__doPostBack` on enter key of textbox but could not succeeded.

Following  is for JQuery dialog

**asp.net**

```
<div id="popupdiv"   title="Basic modal dialog" class="abc" style="display: none">Enter Password        
<asp:TextBox ID="pass" onkeypress="return chkDiscountEnter(this);" ClientIDMode="static"   runat="server" CssClass="textcss" ></asp:TextBox> 

<asp:Button ID="btnDiscountAtEnd" runat="server" style="display:none;" Text="Button" OnClick="btnDiscountAtEnd_Click" />
```

**JQuery to catch enter key on keypress event of textbox**

```
 <script>
        function chkDiscountEnter(e) {
            $(document).keypress(function (e) {
                if ($("#pass").hasClass('textcss') && (e.keycode == 13)) {

                   __doPostBack('<%=btnDiscountAtEnd.UniqueID%>', "");
                    //alert("hi");
    
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a do postback means that in the page load event, you have to pick up the values passed - it can't call  your button code stub directly.

However, you can most certainly fire the .click method/event of that button  you have on the form anyway - thus achieve the same result.

I would add clientID mode to that button, but say you have this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDiscountAtEnd" runat="server" style="display:none;" 
             Text="Button" OnClick="btnDiscountAtEnd_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

So, now in your js, just do this:

```
 $('#btnDiscountAtEnd').click();
```